# [Object][Object] Error Sharepoint Power App Table

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I have the following error when inserting a Table into Power App.

[image]

The reason is that Composition is a choices Column and so is effectively a table within a cell.

[image]

However looking online there do appear to be workarounds but I am struggling to get this to work for my desired table.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/object-Object-Powerapps-and-Sharepoint-list/td-p/172007 The suggestion here is to add a column which somehow for each item displays the record.
My attempt at this:

```
AddColumns('QSAR Analysis Submission Data'[@Composition], "newcolumn", ThisRecord.Composition)
```

But this just returns a similar result. only specific to Composition now.. [[image]

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/DataTable-is-showing-object-Object-in-column-for-data-from/td-p/137040
[image]

AGain this attempt fails.

```
ClearCollect('QSAR Analysis Submission Data', AddColumns('QSAR Analysis Submission Data'[@Composition], "newcolumn", ThisRecord.Composition))
```

Hoping someone more familiar with powerapps code can help.

Comment: If "Composition" is a single selection choice column in SharePoint, try using this: `AddColumns('QSAR Analysis Submission Data'[@Composition], "newColumn", ThisRecord.Composition.Value)`. Use newColumn to show in the table. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, the code provides the same as in the final image.

I have also added another image to Show the Composition choices. Note it is possible to have multiple choices selected too within a cell.

Comment: 'Concat(ThisItem.Composition, Value & ", ")' Appears to be the solution

Comment: Use concat() function for multiple selections

Answer (score 1):

For multiple selection choice columns, try using formula like this:

```
AddColumns('QSAR Analysis Submission Data'[@Composition], "newColumn", Concat(ThisItem.Composition, Value & ", "))
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint List Multi-choice column in Data table showing error](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/SharePoint-List-Multi-choice-column-in-Datatable-showing-error/td-p/370403?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)